# Foreach - Paginação com imagens

Tags: php, paginação

Estou tentando exibir imagens, ao invés de números, na paginação.

Preciso de ajuda para colocar dentro do `for` essas imagens que estão vindo da variavel `$aImages` no `foreach`,

```
       $maximo = 1;
        $pagina = isset($_GET['pagina']) ? ($_GET['pagina']) : '1'; 
        $pagina2 = $pagina + 1;
        $inicio = $pagina - 1;
        $inicio = $maximo * $inicio; 

        //CONSULTA PARA CONTAR TODOS REGISTROS
        $strCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'total_images' FROM posts, images
    WHERE posts.id_posts = images.posts_ID
    AND slug='".$_GET['slug']."'";
            $varstrCount = $crud->verdados($strCount);
            $total = 0;
            if(count($varstrCount)){
                foreach ($varstrCount as $row) {
                        $total = $row["total_imagens"]; 
                }
            }

            //CONSULTA PARA LIMITAR OS REGISTROS NA PAGINAÇÃO
            $resultado =  "SELECT * FROM posts, images
                         WHERE posts.id_post = images.posts_ID
                         AND slug='".$_GET['slug']."' ORDER BY id_posts LIMIT $inicio,$maximo";

            //EXECUTA A CONSULTA            
            $varresultado = $crud->verdados($resultado);

            $max_links = 10;
            $previous = $pagina - 1; 
            $next = $pagina + 1; 
            $pgs = ceil($total / $maximo);  

         //CONSULTA PARA AGRUPAR IMAGENS RELACIONADAS AO ID

          $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT 
                                  posts.*,
                                  COUNT(0) total, 
                                  GROUP_CONCAT(dir_image SEPARATOR '|') images
                                  FROM 
                                    posts
                                 INNER JOIN images ON (posts.id_post = images.post_id )
                                 WHERE
                                   slug=:slug
                                 GROUP BY
                                 id_post
                                  ");
         //EXECUTA A CONSULTA
         $stmt->execute(array(":slug"=>$_GET['slug']));

         while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
         {
             $aImages = explode('|', $row['images']);



           for($i=$pagina-$max_links; $i <= $pgs; $i++) {
               foreach ($aImages as $sImage) {
               echo "<a href='".BASE_URL.$slug."-".($i)."'><img src='".BASE_URL.$sImage."' ></a>";  ;                                       

               }

            }

}
```

A ideia é ter esse resultado final:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essas são a tabelas no DB:

Tabela IMAGES esta assim:

```
id_images | dir_image | post_id
1           image1.jpg  1
2           image2.jpg  1
3           image3.jpg  1
4           image4.jpg  1
5           image5.jpg  2
6           image6.jpg  2
7           image7.jpg  2
8           image8.jpg  2
```

Tabela POSTS:

```
id_post | slug          | title
1         title_post      Title Post 
2         title_post_2    Title Post 2
```

Como exemplo a variavel `$aImages` tem 5 imagens vindas do DB, a ordem imprime corretamente mas cada imagem imprime repetidamente 15 vezes não entendi o motivo, preciso que cada uma imprima apenas uma vez.

Agradeço ajuda

Comment: o for() de dentro está imprimindo a imagem do for each de fora várias vezes. Precisa dele? Se precisa, precisa repensar sua paginação. Eu acho que não é o caso de usar foreach se é pra paginar. E outra coisa, $maximo tem que pegar o tamanho de $aImages.

Comment: Obrigada @Bacco o `for` é responsavel por adicionar o numero da paginação `$i`, não sei como fazer isso sem o for

Answer (score 2):

> Nota: Esta resposta foi postada para uma [edição anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/120048/revisions) da pergunta.

Segue um exemplo bem simples e didático de paginação, para servir de exemplo:

```
$imagens = '/1.jpg|/2.jpg|/3.jpg|/4.jpg|/5.jpg|/6.jpg|/7.jpg|/8.jpg';
$aImages = explode( '|',  $imagens );

$porPagina = 3;
$total = count( $aImages );
$paginas = ceil( $total / $porPagina ); 

for( $pagina = 0; $pagina < $paginas; ++$pagina ) {
   echo 'Pagina ' . ( $pagina + 1 ) . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;

   $offset = $pagina * $porPagina;
   for( $item = $offset ; $item < $total && $item < $offset + $porPagina; ++$item ) {
       echo '<img src="'.BASE_URL.$aImages[$item].'" ></a>' . PHP_EOL;
   }
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/KRWRdk)**.

É claro que no caso, você vai ter que adaptar à situação real do seu código. Se for mostrar apenas uma página por vez, basta eliminar o `for( $pagina` de fora, e definir a variável externamente.

Comment: Obrigada @Bacco seu codigo é limpo objetivo e funcional, mas no meu caso eu aproveito algumas variaveis em outras partes do projeto. Atualizei a pergunta para vc ter uma noção melhor do que estou fazendo

Comment: Basicamente eu fiz alguns nomes pra ilustrar o que é cada coisa. Creio que basta você substituir as coisas pelos nomes certos, que vai funcionar. O simples fato de tirar o loop de fora, e pegar o $pagina do slug já faz o que você pretende. O loop de fora foi só pra você ver o de dentro em funcionamento (e ver como calculei o offset para determinar os ítens da página atual)

Comment: PS: Se não é uma "Paginação" de verdade, e quer mostrar todas as imagens, só fazer o que eu falei nos comentários: por o foreach dentro do for.

Comment: Com o foreach dentro do for aparece 1 imagem por vez na ordem certa mas repetindo varias vezes a sequencia de 5 imagens

Comment: Ja com o for dentro do foreach aparece cada imagem 15 vezes mas sequencia tbm certa

Comment: Não pode misturar o while com o for. Você pode usar o while para montar um array, e usar esse array no for (mas não dentro do while). E dentro do for que vai usar o explode (senão, o array vai ser sempre o mesmo).

Comment: è que dentro do while tem outras parte html e php que estou imprimindo conforme a consuldo do DB como titulo, slug, conteudo, etc. A paginação de imagens esta dentro do conteudo, então se tiro o while desconfigura todo o restante e até mesmo a propria paginação